# Как скопировать изменения в node_modules c GitHub?

Tags: github, npm

Я установил плагин для Quill.
Он не корректно работает если его устанавливать через WebPack.

[Я нашёл ответ как исправить эту ошибку](https://github.com/BrandtM/quill-image-resize-module/commit/ce0199f09d415d84a2035c8479fbd78696e244d1#diff-e51a812012d0786072a738d5e7a4a773R1)

Для того что бы её исправить, надо исменить файл 
image-resize.min.js

Но он очень длинный. Я не могу скопировать изменения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне грамматно получить этот файл ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справа от имени файла три точки -> показать файл -> raw.

Прямая [ссылка](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BrandtM/quill-image-resize-module/ce0199f09d415d84a2035c8479fbd78696e244d1/image-resize.min.js)